# gulp error handling for dependent task

Tags: javascript, build, gulp

Please find the content of the `gulpfile.js` as below.

The task `uglify` depends on the task `jshint`. Currently when I run `gulp`, both the tasks get executed, irrespective of the outcome of the `jshint` task. I don't want the `uglify` task to get executed when there are 'jshint' error(s).

In other words, when ever there are dependent tasks, I don't want the subsequent tasks to get executed, if there are error detected by the preceding task.

Is it possible in `gulp`?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('jshint', function () {
  return gulp.src(['assets/js/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'));
});

gulp.task('uglify', ['jshint'], function() {
  return gulp.src('assets/js/**/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets-min/js/'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['jshint', 'uglify']);
```

Please refer the below `console output - not desired`. Though there had been `jshint` error, the `uglify` task ran successfully.

I have also created a GitHub repository with the boilerplate code for the above mentioned.
Please find the same at [@sarbbottam/gulp-workflow](https://github.com/sarbbottam/gulp-workflow).

**Console out of the undesired workflow**
[image: console output - not desired]

**Console out of the expected workflow**
[image: console output - expected]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For `JSHint`, there is a built-in reporter for this purpose, `fail`. If an error occurs, it will stop your `gulp` process.

You just have to redefine your `task` like :

```
gulp.task('jshint', function () {
  return gulp.src(['assets/js/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('fail'))
})
```

With other tasks, you can add an `error callback` on it and exit the process to prevent  subsequent tasks to run.

Here is an example with `ngmin` (cause `uglify` is hard to break, but it will be the same) :

```
function handleError (err) {
  console.log(err.toString())
  process.exit(-1)
}

gulp.task('min', function () {
  return gulp.src(['assets/js/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(ngmin())
    .on('error', handleError)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, ``.pipe(jshint.reporter('fail')`` solves the problem, for ``jshint``. Is there any ``generic`` API? I mean, what for ``gulp-sass`` etc? Is ``error callback`` is generic one?

Comment: For me yes, the generic thing to do is to add this `callback` on each task you want to break in case of error, but I could be wrong. And one thing, I know this is an example, but instead of make two different tasks, you can launch the `uglify` right after the `jshint` in the same task to reduce your `gulp` logic.

Comment: I guess, your suggestion of clubbing both the task would be ideal, I have just started off with ``gulp``, so still trying out. I have updated the question and the [git repo](https://github.com/sarbbottam/gulp-workflow)

Comment: Yeah that's the way to go. You should remove the updated code from your question, because it provide the answer in it, someone that comes here will not understand why you have a problem. You can keep the expected image.

Answer (score 5):

To complement Aperçu's answer, if you don't want gulp to just exit (because you have watcher running) then you can do the following:

```
gulp.task('min', function(done) {
  return gulp.src(['assets/js/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(ngmin())
    .on('error', done);
});
```

This will prevent the next task that depends on this one to run but your watchers will still be running.

Comment: Saved me from adding another question

Comment: Hi ! Do you mind expending on that ? What is done supposed to be in that context ? I'm in this exact situation, I want not to run the next task, however I still want the watcher to keep going, just can't figure it out ! Thanks !

Comment: done is just a nodejs style callback function passed by gulp that allows you to specify when your task is done or alternatively specify that your task has failed by passing a non empty error parameter to it. If you pass err to it then gulp will know your task has failed and will not run next one.